# Securely dealing with passwords in Cocoa and in NSTask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, security

Let's say I have an NSSecureTextField in my app. Is it okay for me to grab the password into an NSString variable (as I normally would) and pass it around my app's code? Is it considered secure, or do I have to somehow encrypt the string variable within the app's code?

Also (and this is an **absolutely critical** part of my question): Is it secure to pass an NSString password gotten from an NSSecureTextField, via an NSPipe, into the standard input of an NSTask, to supply a password to a command-line tool? My main worry is that the OS would log the password someplace, which would be terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, as soon as password leaves secure storage (i.e. `NSSecureTextField`) and stored as plain text in memory (`NSString` variable) it is not longer considered secure. All the more passing plain text password to OS environment is not secure. It's relatively difficult for potential attacker to get it in the first case (from the memory of your app), and relatively easy in the second case.

Comment: So it's totally unacceptable to, say, make a password-protected tar archive by calling tar with NSTask, passing in the password via stdin?

Comment: It all depends. It's very hard to achieve high level of security, especially then you can't control all stages there secure information is involved. So it's almost always a balance choice between reasonable amount of security for given situation. For example consider passing not a password, but a hash of a password as a password to tar. Even if it will be intercepted, at least original password (which can be used in other places) will not be compromised.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe to pass unencrypted data around your application. Other applications cannot access your address space, so as long as you take care of security vulnerabilities, no one can get it. However, you should encrypt it before passing it to another application, if possible. You can't be sure it won't be intercepted between the two.

Comment: @Josh The attacker would have to know where to look. If he is going to do that, he could also get the password directly from the text field, so it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @Josh: What did you say? No need to withdraw the comment! I could have learned something from the conversation :)